# How to access the entire Pycharm Run Tool Window outcome?

Tags: python, pycharm

When I run my script in PyCharm, it prints out a lot of stuff in Run Tool Window. At some point it reaches the maximum number of lines. When it happens it continues to print into the Run Tool Window, but the top lines start disappearing. Is there any way I can access the entire outcome of a running script? Is it maybe saved anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

On the right side of the run window, there is a small wrench symbol below the green triangle. Click that and you are taken to an options window. If you click on the tab "Logs", there is a checkbox that says "Save console output to file". Try that one.

Answer (score 0):

For PyCharm 2021.3.1 (and I think for most of the PyCharm versions):

1. Go to **File > Settings** (Ctrl + Alt + S)
2. Select **Editor > General > Console**

And tick the `Override console cycle buffer size` then you can edit the size to your needs.

[image: Settings image example]